# ACR122U authentication not working with NTAG 213

Tags: nfc

I'm using an ACR122U with an NTAG213 card that has read and right protection with the password XX XX XX XX.

I'm using the ACS ScriptingTool to send APDU commands to the card, but I cannot get it to Authenticate. Here is what I'm sending:

ACR122U APDU Command
< FF 00 00 00 07 D4 42 1B xx xx xx xx

> D5 43 00 00 00 90 00

ACR122U APDU Command
< FF 00 00 00 07 D4 42 30 04

> D5 43 02 90 00

As you can see, it is not reading back to me the data written on the read/write protected page 04. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a better way to be sending APDU commands to cards than my current setup?